# How to run multiple jmx in non GUI mode?

Tags: linux, jmeter, jvm, execution, distributed-testing

Having trouble running multiple JMX files in non GUI mode in Linux. Doesn't seem to be spinning up multiple instances of the JMeter JVM service. Any help would be much appreciated.

Failing command:

```
sudo $JMETER/jmeter -n -r -t $JMETER/test1.jmx & sudo $JMETER/jmeter -n -r -t $JMETER/test2.jmx &
```

See attachment below for error 'Engine is busy - try again later' only test 1 gets started and the test 2 doesn't.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to execute different tests at the same time in the [distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/). As of current [JMeter version 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) this is **not supported** as remote slave JMeter engine can only execute one test at a time.

So either consider running the tests locally (without the distributed mode) or make sure to run as many slave instances as you need using [different RMI ports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) in order to have:

- Unique master and unique slave(s) running test 1
- Unique master and unique slave(s) running test 2
- etc.